# Electron JS Mac Build IPC communication issue

Tags: node.js, reactjs, electron, ipc

Here is my code

electron.js

```
ipcMain.on('getConnectionsList', () => {
  window.webContents.send('connectionsList', conns_data)
})
```

preload.js

```
getConnectionsList: (_init) => {
  ipcRenderer.send('getConnectionsList', _init)
},
connectionsList: (list) => {
  ipcRenderer.on('connectionsList', list)
},
```

App.js

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  window.multisig.getConnectionsList(false)
  window.multisig.connectionsList((_event, list) => {
    setItemData(list)
  })
}, [])
```

1. It is working well in the development environment.
2. It is also working well on the windows and linux production build.
3. It is also working well on the MAC development environment.

But on the MAC production build, I am not getting any data which I am supposed to see.

Can any one please help me on this issue please, Thank you.

I tried using the official documentation of electronjs to overcome this issue but cannot find any solution specifically for MAC.

Comment: Does it work with `invoke`/`handle` ?

Comment: Yes, used the invoke and handle but its still not working. @Arkellys

Answer (score 0):

Due to not knowing the exact circumstance of your issue, you'll need to debug the backend side.

There is most likely something crashing it, the reason it only crashes on production on mac is most likely due to stricter policies.

For instance, my sequelize was trying to store an sqlite file in the root 'code' directory (not userdata/appdata) which can only be done in development, mac picked up on this and disallowed it, windows did not and I assume temporarily stored the file.

If you can, get the error logs of your backend, but it's not a electron and mac issue.